# Don't understand why attributed range within a text view isn't coming out with blue attributes

Tags: ios

I'm trying add two tappable links within the text of a text view, I've consulted some past questions and this is my code. However the problem is it displays like this:

[image]

When the "link1" and "link2" portions are supposed to appear as blue. Why are they not appearing?

```
        termsAndConditionsTextView.text = "Some text with link1 and link2"
        let attributedString            = termsAndConditionsTextView.attributedText?.mutableCopy(with: nil) as! NSMutableAttributedString
        let blueTextLinkAttributes      = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
        let string                      = termsAndConditionsTextView.text! as NSString
        let tcRange                     = string.range(of: "link1")
        let ppRange                     = string.range(of: "link2")

        attributedString.addAttributes(blueTextLinkAttributes, range: tcRange)
        attributedString.addAttributes(blueTextLinkAttributes, range: ppRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.placeholder1.com", range: tcRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.placeholder2.com", range: ppRange)
        termsAndConditionsTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

termsAndConditionsTextView is a UITextView outlet

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code using Xcode by adding UITextView programmatically and using story board. but i couldn't find any error, it's work as you want.this is project i have created using your code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var termsAndConditionTextView: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    termsAndConditionTextView.text = "Some text with link1 and link2"
    let attributedString            = termsAndConditionTextView.attributedText?.mutableCopy(with: nil) as! NSMutableAttributedString
    let blueTextLinkAttributes      = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
    let string                      = termsAndConditionTextView.text! as NSString
    let tcRange                     = string.range(of: "link1")
    let ppRange                     = string.range(of: "link2")

    attributedString.addAttributes(blueTextLinkAttributes, range: tcRange)
    attributedString.addAttributes(blueTextLinkAttributes, range: ppRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.placeholder1.com", range: tcRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "www.placeholder2.com", range: ppRange)
    termsAndConditionTextView.attributedText = attributedString


    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: That is mysterious.

Comment: yep man..i try to figure out what is the point.But i used completely our code just copy and paste to my project.